How to write constraints for an indicator function such that if x = 0 then y = 1, and otherwise y = 0?
Currently working on an optimization problem using pyomo. One constraint I need to make is to limit the number of times a situation occurs - Essentially when my variable x = 0.
So I would like an indicator variable as described in the title so that I can add the constraint $\sum y_{i} \leq 5$
The variable x can take on any integer value, and so needs to pass three cases: When x = 0, when x > 0 (i.e) 1 and when x < 0 (i.e) -1.
I have attempted a few variations of Big-M constraints such as:
$x \geq \epsilon - My$
That approach works fine for the first two cases, but when x is negative then y=1 which is not what we need. Other approaches I have tried run into similar (maybe flipped) issues. Is there a way to write these constraints or do I need to rethink how I am formulating the problem to begin with?
Would like to keep the problem linear if possible so constraints on $x^2$ are not ideal.

Can you describe your "Big-M constraints" technique or feature more? Is it like to minimise $y$, subject to $x\ge \epsilon - My$, $y\ge 0$, and $y$ integer?

It seems that you can define a step function $a$ where
$$a = \begin{cases}1, &x\le 0\
0, &x> 0
\end{cases}$$
Then define another one similarly with negated inputs:
$$b = \begin{cases}0, &x< 0\
1, &x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
Then $y=a+b-1$.

For integer variable $x\in\{-M,\dots,M\}$ and binary variable $y$, you can enforce $x=0 \iff y=1$ by introducing binary variables $y^-$ and $y^+$ and linear constraints
$$y^- + y + y^+ = 1 \\
-M y^- + 0y + 1y^+ \le x \le -1y^- + 0y + M y^+
$$

Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Are you able to explain a bit more or point me to a reference where I can learn to solve through similar problems? I wouldn't have thought to introduce the two other binary variables.

The Operations Research StackExchange has a lot of questions like this.  In particular, see  https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2632/500
